# "Failed to open dir" error when generating a PDF file with TCPDF

Tags: symfony, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I'm trying to generate a PDF with TCPDF. I have the data to render in the PDF, I created the controller for that, but I'm getting the following error:

```
    Warning: opendir(/home/symfony/pricing/web/tcpdf/fonts/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory
500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException
```

I don't know where it comes from.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it means `opendir()` can't find the directory supplied. try to search your files for 'web/tcpdf/fonts/' to locate that code and supply the correct location of the fonts